# When utilizing qsort() on a tree made of structs, I am not receiving a sorted array back

Tags: c

Using the `qsort` on a tree made of structs, I am not getting a sorted array back.

I've tried manipulating the comparator function and `qsort` but not sure what the problem is.

```
typedef struct nodeBST { // struct
    char *key;
    int count;
    struct nodeBST *left;
    struct nodeBST *right;
} nodeBST;
```

---

```
qsort(*words, numTokensActual, sizeof(nodeBST), comparator); //qsort
```

---

```
for (i = 0; i < numTokensActual; i++) {
    printf("sorted words[%d]:%s: %d \n", i,
           ((struct nodeBST *)words[i])->key,
           ((struct nodeBST *)words[i])->count); //traverse to print
}
```

---

```
struct nodeBST *words[4]; //creation of array and malloc for space

int z;

for (z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
    words[z] = malloc(sizeof(nodeBST));
}
```

---

```
int comparator(const void *p, const void *q) { //compare function
    struct nodeBST *a = (struct nodeBST **)p;    
    struct nodeBST *b = (struct nodeBST **)q;

    return a->count - b->count;
}
```

---

```
printf("%d \n"((struct nodeBST*)words[i])->count); //print output
```

---

```
int numTokensActual = AddToArray(root, words, 0);
```

---

```
int AddToArray(nodeBST *node,  nodeBST **arr, int i) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return i;

    if (node->left != NULL)
        i = AddToArray(node->left, arr, i);

    //printf("Adding To Array[%d]: %s:%d\n",i, node->key, node->count);
    //arr[i] = node;
    arr[i] = newNodeBST2(node->key, node->count);
    //printf("added array[%d]: %s\n", i, arr[i]->key);
    i++;
    if (node->right != NULL)
        i = AddToArray(node->right, arr, i);

    return i;
}
```

I expect the output to give me a sorted array but the output is:

```
0 
0 
49 
6
```

Comment: `struct nodeBST * a = (struct nodeBST**) p;` is wrong on a couple of levels. [You need to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before asking on SO.

Comment: My input for the array are words from a text file that I store as tokens and then create an array of structs in which i take the "count" from or the frequencies of the words. The third word does not appear 49 times.

Comment: StoryTeller, I have debugged my code but can not find the issue. It is simply not getting the right comparisons.

Comment: `qsort` is for continuously allocated memory, for an array. You are building a tree. You have to write `qsort` algorithm yourself.

Comment: Beyond the fact that `qsort` is inappropriate for anything but an array, not much can be said from the code fragments posted. You must post a complete program with definitions and functions for us to see how you use `qsort` and other potential problems.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an array, read the documentation:

> The qsort() function sorts an array with nmemb elements of size size.

We can use qsort to get a sorted list of the items without changing your data structure if you build a temporary array with `count` and a pointer to the items like:

```
struct {
    int count;
    struct nodeBST *node;
} tempSortedNodes[numTokensActual];
```

Traverse your tree and populate the `sorted` array, then you can qsort it. Note the sorted version becomes invalid when the tree is updated.

Another approach would be to have another tree using `count` as the key instead. That secondary tree would also be invalidated whenever the original tree is updated. However, we could update both trees if you need to maintain a count-sorted version of the tree all the times.

A sort algorithm for a tree, as suggested in the comments, is not a good idea at all. That would be equivalent to create a new tree using `count` as key as I suggested.